# jQuery: .parent() wont hide if numerical range begins at 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I am having some issues with using a numerical range detection within an element, to then hide another element. It seems to work fine when the range starts at 1+, but it breaks at 0+. Their are different iterations of code I have tried, but so far no luck.

This is the website I am trying to use my greasemonkey script on:
https://openuserjs.org/?orderBy=updated&orderDir=desc

The purpose: I would like to hide a listed item, if it has 0-100 installs.

Here is my script: https://ghostbin.com/paste/zujku

Here are the three variations of code I have tried using but failed:

```
$("TR .text-center.td-fit").each(function() { 
if ($(this).text() >= 0 && $(this).text() <= 100){
$(this).parent().hide();
}
});


$(document).ready(function(){
var tds = $("TR .text-center.td-fit").filter(function() {
return (+$(this).text() > 0 && +$(this).text() < 100);
});
tds.parent().hide();
});


$("TR .text-center.td-fit").each(function() { 
if ($(this).text() >= 0 && $(this).text() <= 100){
$(this).parent().hide();
}
});
```

Note: ".text-center.td-fit" is the 'installs' element on the main list item (TR)

Comment: `.text()` returns a **string**. If you want to perform a numeric comparison, you have to make it a number explicitly.

Comment: `+$(this).text()`

Comment: does my 2nd variation not have that already being used?

Comment: The code in the linked ghostbin does not look like what you posted. If the table cells really have numeric strings, then the second one should work so long as you change it to `>= 0` instead of `> 0`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, it unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: @Pointy When you compare a string and a number, it converts the string to a number first, so you don't need an explicit conversion.

Comment: Can you make an executable stack snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: `.text-center.td-fit` also selects the **Rating** cells. So you're hiding anything with a rating between 0 and 100 as well.

Comment: @Barmar yea I guess you're right; I always do it for my own sanity and for consistency since equality comparison is so crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("tr.tr-link").each(function() { 
    var num = parseInt($(this).find('td.text-center.td-fit > p').first().text());
    if (num >= 0 && num <= 100) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Tested and functioning properly. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

I used AdBlock element hider in the firefox add-on store to figure this out. With a few combinations/try's, I found this combination to work

AdBlock Element Hider selection:

```
THEAD + * TD:first-child + .text-center.td-fit > P
```

---

Current working version:

```
$("THEAD + * TD:first-child + .text-center.td-fit > P").each(function() { 
if ($(this).text() >= 0 && $(this).text() <= 70){
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    }
});
```