# jQuery: hide .parent if child has HTML numerical range style value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I am using a Greasemonkey script called **[Youtube Video Ratings Bar with Power Meter](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/2302-youtube-video-ratings-bar-with-power-meter)**, it places a bar under each video on YouTube, that displays it's ratings, likes, dislikes, etc. This is very useful, however I wanted to take it a step further. Child/inner element:

```
<div class="powerBar" style="width: 26.1181%;"></div>
```

As you can see, the child element **class="powerBar"**, is a main determining feature of a videos popularity. It has a **style="width: 26.1181%"** attribute, a random numerical percentage value for each video the bar is on. I am curious how you can hide the parent element, if the inner class/child **.powerBar**, has less than 75% of its style width. Parent element:

```
<li class="yt-shelf-grid-item">
```

Now, I had previously asked a question pertaining somewhat similarity. If the code from the **[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40033799/5311141)** I had asked can be used, that would be most awesome. Thank you for taking time out of your day.

---

working version: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40065508/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        youtube hide powerbar
// @namespace   hides videos with low popularity
// @include     *www.youtube.com*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

setInterval(function() {

  function getWidthPercent(element) {
    return parseFloat(element.style.width) || 0;
  }

  $(".likesBar").each(function() {
    if (getWidthPercent(this) < 88) $(this).closest(".video-list-item").css( "opacity", "0.1" );
  });

}, 2000);
// requires https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/2302-youtube-video-ratings-bar-with-power-meter
```

The interval is there to regularly check for DOM updates, eg when using the progressive loading of videos feature or due to the other Greasemonkey script loading rating information asynchronously.

Comment: im playing with it, but no luck yet getting it working.

Comment: `element[0]` should be `element`, since `powerbar` is an HTML element. After the `if`, `powerbar` should be `$(powerbar)` for the same reason as above.

Comment: try the youtube rating bar script with greasemonkey if you want, the goal is to hide the video completely that's listed in subscriptions tab or home.

https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/2302-youtube-video-ratings-bar-with-power-meter

Comment: @mike-mccaughan can you provide a working example with jsfiddle?

Comment: it mostly works, it hides the powerbar, not the main parent/video (.yt-shelf-grid-item), so i had to add in total, 7 .parent()'s

Comment: i changed the .powerbar to .likesbar and 75 to 88

Comment: the first working revision http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40065508/3 works, the newest one doesnt seem to.

Comment: replaced .closest .yt-shelf-grid-item, and used jquery 2.0.3, now it works

Answer (score 0):

Is the width of every power bar the same, regardless of the rating? I'm not sure, wondering if the actual width might change for different ratings.

Is the bar itself not contained within a parent element? That would make sense. If not, then it should be simple enough to work out what 70% of your width is:

```
var powerBarWidth = parseInt($(".powerBar").css("width").replace('px', ''));
var powerBarPercentage = ((powerBarWidth / 100) * 70);
```

Comment: no the powerbar is on every video and is different on every video, the math calculates like, dislikes, views and such, try the script yourself if you want.

Comment: It's just a strange question, you want to check if a value is 70% of itself, maybe the powerbar is an element within a parent - it's width changes to reflect what level or rating - if that's that case it's the width of the parent element that's important. I'm just trying to figure it out, sorry.

Comment: the .powerbar is a child element, within the parent I named, if the width percentage style is less then X.X%, then hide the parent.

Comment: the child powerbar is the one with the style width random percentage